# Load Multiple files from Folder using dill in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dill

I got a folder with 100 *.sav files, I have to load all in to a list, file names saved as my_files_0,my_files_1,my_files_2,my_files_3....

So, I tried:

```
import dill
my_files = []
files_name_list = glob.glob('c:/files/*.sav')
for i in np.arange(1, len(files_name_list)):
    with open('c:/files/my_files_%i.sav'%i, 'rb') as f: my_files = dill.load(f)
my_files
```

Here `my_files` list has only one file in it. I need all 100 files in the list, so I can access them based on index my_files[0]…..

Comment: Is this has to be done using dill?

Comment: yes, its modelling files, joblib and pickle not working, so I am using dill, but if there is an option I can try, but I have to reproduce the error if I save as joblib or pickle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you only have one file in `my_files` is that you are continually overwriting the last result.  I think what you meant to do was append the new result each time you iterate over your list:

```
import dill
my_files = []
files_name_list = glob.glob('c:/files/*.sav')
for i in np.arange(1, len(files_name_list)):
    with open('c:/files/my_files_%i.sav'%i, 'rb') as f:
        my_files.append(dill.load(f))
```

Also, note in your solution, you don't need to do a `f.close()` when you are using `with` to open `f` -- it's closed when it leaves the `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

I used array instead of list, it worked

```
file_array=[0]*len(files_name_list)
for i in np.arange(0, len(file_name_list)):
    with open('c:/files/my_files_%i.sav'%i, 'rb') as f: 
        file_array[i] = dill.load(f)
        f.close()
```